# How to get the checked items from a multi choice item in a Alert.Builder?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Is there a way to get some infomation about the checked items in the next Alert.Builder? I need to save some booleans in SharedPreferences when somebody clicked the positive button. Those booleans are from the choices the user made in the alert. How can I get them?

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("type_settings", MODE_PRIVATE);

        boolean[] selectedTypes = getSelectedTypes(preferences);

        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.menu_type)
                .setTitle(R.string.list_dialog_title)
                .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.select_type_items, selectedTypes,
                        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton, boolean isChecked) {
                            }
                        })
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.types_save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = preferences.edit();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.types_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .create();
        builder.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem in some way, but i don't know if it's a good practice. Here is the code:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("type_settings", MODE_PRIVATE);

        final String[] availableTypes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.select_type_items);
        final boolean[] selectedTypes = getSelectedTypes(preferences, availableTypes);

        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.menu_type)
                .setTitle(R.string.list_dialog_title)
                .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.select_type_items, selectedTypes,
                        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton, boolean isChecked) {
                                selectedTypes[whichButton] = isChecked;
                            }
                        })
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.types_save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = preferences.edit();
                        saveSelectedTypes(prefEditor, availableTypes, selectedTypes);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.types_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .create();
        builder.show();
```

Comment: Good solution. But saving only the selected items to the prefs is the right way. You are storing all the items, even the unchecked ones. Well if it suits your needs.

Comment: I think I will need the unchecked ones too, but anyways, my array is not very large, just 15 elements.

Comment: can you include the code of saveSelectedTypes? i want to save the values of the selecteditem in sharedpreferences

Answer (score 10):

You could use `getCheckedItemIds()` or `getCheckedItemPositions ()` to get a list of checked items from the listview. You should use `AlertDialog.getListView()` to get the dialog's listview first.

```
mAlert.getListView().getCheckedItemPositions ();
```

Answer (score 0):

For storage efficiency, you could convert the boolean array to an integer before storing it as a preference. But beware, the boolean array that initializes the AlertDialog list has the reverse order of the boolean array results from the AlertDialog. (Seems to be a consistent reversal: happens on OS 2.3.6 and 4.2.2 ... I haven't checked any other versions.)